# Datetime conversion issue pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp, weekday

I have a pandas dataframe with the first column of type "datetime64[ns]" on python3.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import datetime as dt

d = {'Date': [np.datetime64('2017-12-31','ns'), np.datetime64('2018-01-01','ns'), np.datetime64('2018-01-02','ns'), np.datetime64('2018-01-03','ns')], 
     'Prices': [9.62, 9.5, 9.73, 9.45]}
analytics = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
analytics['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(analytics['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
Eyear = 2018
Emonth = 1
Eday = 3
###days
#last day
last = dt.datetime(Eyear, Emonth, Eday)
#1y
dtvar = dt.datetime(Eyear-1, Emonth, Eday)

yr1 = dtvar - BDay(1) if (dtvar.weekday() == 5 or dtvar.weekday() == 6) else dtvar
yr1_plus1 = yr1 + BDay(1)
yr1ct = len(analytics[yr1_plus1:last])

print(yr1ct)
```

I keep having this error coming up:

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers [2017-01-02 00:00:00] of class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'

I am trying to find the first business day of one year ago, and find the number of business days in between those 2 dates.

I think that the problem might be that the DataFrame has one type of time format while the variables that are most important for the further operations "last" and "dtvar" are of datetime.datetime, which I need to use the .weekday() formula.
What's the best way to deal with dates in this case?
Because I have seen thousands of different date types around among pandas, numpy and datetime. I am kind of new to python and no matter how hard I tried, I couldn't find a way out.

Thanks so much in advance for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe is not indexed by `Date` column. You will need to [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) before slicing.

```
>>> analytics.set_index("Date")[yr1_plus1:last]
```